# How to call a C# method from asp.net side?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

This seems to be a common question but I could not find a relevant answer

I have a aspx page and in it, 
I've made a list of "a href" tags that is generated from my C# code behind.
Now i want to send data based on which of the "a href" tag i have selected and pass it into my C# code which will then populate my popup with required information:

The process

> > "a href click" -> call c# method -> populate popup with data

I am stuck at how to pass data from the "a href click" to the c#.

I tried using .OnServerClick but my popup didn't even pop up.

> > For starters, i would like to try: When i Click a **"a href"** tag it would call my changeTitle() method from c# which will change the title of the pop up. If i can get this working, i should be able to manage the rest

[image: popup]

c# method:

```
public void changeTitle()
{
    this.modalTitle.InnerHtml = "Goodbye world";
}
```

Do tell me if you need more information please, I really hope to get this working

Comment: Did you hear about query strings?

Comment: no, what is it? Jquery?

Comment: A query string is part of the url: http://example.com/?myParamName=myParam
The query string is behind the ? Your server can receive this data

Comment: But a little less firm: You should consider using data-xxx attributes, which are nicely available in jQuery and make an AJAX call to your server, which then delivers the data or the html snippet for the overlay window

Comment: but I have to send the data to my C# side to call a method before it gets back to my .aspx page

Comment: Depending on how you construct your page, you can use AJAX.net http://www.asp.net/ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really look into learning more about how jQuery and ASP.NET can work together. I highly recommend starting at [Dave Ward's site](http://www.encosia.com).

Here is a blog entry about using jQuery to call ASP.NET server methods (page methods are a great way to get quick hooks into server-side logic that can pass data back to the client-side):
[Using jQuery To Directly Call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

I have used this technique in many projects over the years and I think once you start learning the power of jQuery you will want to use this approach over strictly server-side controls.

Comment: great it works like a charm, easily customized too. Thanks! @Karl

Answer (score 1):

If ASP.NET WebForms is being used (remember to specify which "flavor" of ASP.NET), a [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cd4z1zs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) control may be a suitable approach<sup>1</sup>.

*A LinkButton works like a a normal Button that looks like a hyperlink* and causes a PostBack when clicked. (This is different from "normal" hyperlinks that change the browser location.)

The `OnClick` attrtibute specifies the server callback handler and the `Command` and `CommandArguments` can be used to associate specific data with the control that are available on the server during the LinkButton's click callback.

---

<sup>1</sup> While my current preferred form of development is a *thick client* with a *thin backend* (e.g. not WebForms), switching to use "Page Methods" or "AJAX" requires rewriting the front-end/HTML to act on the response as appropriate. A LinkButton on the other hand, simply "works" with the normal ASP.NET WebForms lifecycle/infrastructure without any additional work.

Comment: @BloopieBloops How do you think the LinkButton renders in HTML? It is an "a" element. This can be inspected with the Developer Tools that ship with modern browsers.